# Add bottom border line to UI TextField view in SwiftUI / Swift / Objective-C / Xamarin

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin, swiftui

I would like to keep the border at the bottom part only in `UITextField`.
But I don't know how we can keep it on the bottom side.

Can you please advise me?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

I am creating custom `textField` to make it reusable component for SwiftUI

**SwiftUI**

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    var placeHolder: String
    @Binding var value: String
    
    var lineColor: Color
    var width: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(self.placeHolder, text: $value)
            .padding()
            .font(.title)
            
            Rectangle().frame(height: self.width)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20).foregroundColor(self.lineColor)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
@Binding var userName: String
@Binding var password: String

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        CustomTextField(placeHolder: "Username", value: $userName, lineColor: .white, width: 2)
        CustomTextField(placeHolder: "Password", value: $password, lineColor: .white, width: 2)
    }
}
```

---

---

**Swift 5.0**

I am using Visual Formatting Language (VFL) here, This will allow adding a line to any `UIControl`.

You can create a `UIView` extension class like `UIView+Extention.swift`

```
import UIKit

enum LinePosition {
    case top
    case bottom
}

extension UIView {
    func addLine(position: LinePosition, color: UIColor, width: Double) {
        let lineView = UIView()
        lineView.backgroundColor = color
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This is important!
        self.addSubview(lineView)

        let metrics = ["width" : NSNumber(value: width)]
        let views = ["lineView" : lineView]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[lineView]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))

        switch position {
        case .top:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[lineView(width)]", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        case .bottom:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[lineView(width)]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
textField.addLine(position: .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM, color: .darkGray, width: 0.5)
```

---

**Objective C:**

You can add this helper method to your global helper class(I used global class method) or in the same view controller(using an instance method).

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    LINE_POSITION_TOP,
    LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM
} LINE_POSITION;


- (void) addLine:(UIView *)view atPosition:(LINE_POSITION)position withColor:(UIColor *)color lineWitdh:(CGFloat)width {
    // Add line
    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [lineView setBackgroundColor:color];
    [lineView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view addSubview:lineView];
    
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"width" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:width]};
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"lineView" : lineView};
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lineView]|" options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
    
    switch (position) {
        case LINE_POSITION_TOP:
            [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[lineView(width)]" options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
            break;
            
        case LINE_POSITION_BOTTOM:
            [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lineView(width)]|" options: 0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[self addLine:self.textField atPosition:LINE_POSITION_TOP withColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] lineWitdh:0.5];
```

---

**Xamarin code:**

```
 var border = new CALayer();
 nfloat width = 2;
 border.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
 border.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, textField.Frame.Size.Height - width, textField.Frame.Size.Width, textField.Frame.Size.Height);
 border.BorderWidth = width;
 textField.Layer.AddSublayer(border);
 textField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 160):

If you want to do **without knowing frames** beforehand, **without subclassing** and **without Autolayout**:

**Swift 5** /   **Swift 4.x** /  **Swift 3.x**

```
extension UITextField {
  func setBottomBorder() {
    self.borderStyle = .none
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
  }
}
```

Call as `yourTextField.setBottomBorder()` from anywhere without making sure of the frames to be right.

The Result looks like this:

> [image: sample]

**Swift UI**

```
struct MyTextField: View {
  var myPlaceHolder: String
  @Binding var text: String

  var underColor: Color
  var height: CGFloat

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField(self.myPlaceHolder, text: $text)
        .padding()
        .font(.title)

        Rectangle().frame(height: self.height)
            .padding(.horizontal, 24).foregroundColor(self.underColor)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it really work? I'm not getting any bottom line

Comment: It works for me, can you show some of your code, so we can look into

Comment: I call it inside `awakeFromNib()` method and it does not return any bottom line. Same for calling it in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: Try in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I would need to set outlets for my textfields, I'd prefer to do this inside textField class

Comment: @DCDC: I ran into this problem while using background Color for textField, so I removed the background color and it worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I set it in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @markhorrocks Can you share your result? I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: If we change the background color to clear color, its not working.

Comment: @Satyam Background color of `UITextField`?

Comment: yes. If we change white color to clear color in self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor its not working

Comment: Can you make this work with just a simple textView?

Answer (score 44):

You can create a subclass of `UITextField` as shown below:

```
class TextField : UITextField {

    override var tintColor: UIColor! {

        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let startingPoint   = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)
        let endingPoint     = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        path.addLine(to: endingPoint)
        path.lineWidth = 2.0

        tintColor.setStroke()

        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Comment: Best approach to do. I just wanted to know how to change underline color while editing or during the method "didBeginEditing" and change color on "didEndEditing"

Comment: See the updated answer, set the `tintColor` in `didBeginEditing` and `didEndEditing`

Comment: This is the solution I used. I subtracted 4 from maxY to move the underline closer to the text entry.

Answer (score 23):

None of these solutions really met my expectations. I wanted to **subclass** the TextField since I don't want to set the border manually all the time. I also wanted to **change the border color** e.g. for an error. So here's my solution with `Anchors`:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {

            // Setup Bottom-Border

            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            bottomBorder = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
            bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xE2DCD1) // Set Border-Color
            bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            addSubview(bottomBorder)

            bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            bottomBorder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
            bottomBorder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
            bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true // Set Border-Strength

    }
}
```

---- Optional ----

To change the color add sth like this to the `CustomTextField Class`:

```
@IBInspectable var hasError: Bool = false {
    didSet {

        if (hasError) {

            bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        } else {

            bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xE2DCD1)

        }

    }
}
```

And to trigger the Error call this after you created an instance of CustomTextField

```
textField.hasError = !textField.hasError
```

[image]

Hope it helps someone ;)

Comment: Best solution so far, you can even modify it for other "validation" states

Answer (score 22):

```
 extension UITextField {  
  func setBottomBorder(color:String) {
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(1.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: color)!.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width,   width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

and then just do this:

```
yourTextField.setBottomBorder(color: "#3EFE46")
```

Comment: I was thinking to do like this, but if we use this in `viewDidLoad()`, the frame would be incorrect. So we have 2 choices : `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidAppear()`. But `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` called multiple times and calling from `viewDidAppear()` would not be good experience.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will also won't work if the textfield is nested inside `multiple View`. You'll get multiple broder.

Answer (score 13):

You can create this extension outside class and replace width with whatever borderWidth you want.

**Swift 4**

```
extension UITextField
{
    func setBottomBorder(withColor color: UIColor)
    {
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let width: CGFloat = 1.0

        let borderLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - width, width: self.frame.width, height: width))
        borderLine.backgroundColor = color
        self.addSubview(borderLine)
    }
}
```

**Original**

```
extension UITextField
{
    func setBottomBorder(borderColor: UIColor)
    {
        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        let width = 1.0

        let borderLine = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.frame.height - width, self.frame.width, width))
        borderLine.backgroundColor = borderColor
        self.addSubview(borderLine)
    }
}
```

and then add this to your viewDidLoad replacing yourTextField with your UITextField variable and with any color you want in the border

```
yourTextField.setBottomBorder(UIColor.blackColor())
```

This basically adds a view with that color at the bottom of the text field.

Comment: Great solution, works with a clear background unlike some of the others.

Comment: remember to add func call to viewDidLayoutSubviews() if using auto layout :) otherwise your line will not correctly match frame.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

**Objective C**

```
        [txt.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [txt.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [txt.layer setBorderWidth: 0.0];
        [txt.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
        [txt.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
        [txt.layer setShadowRadius:2.0f];
        txt.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        txt.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
        txt.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
        txt.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
```

**Swift**

```
        txt.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        txt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        txt.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        txt.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        txt.layer.masksToBounds = false
        txt.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        txt.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        txt.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        txt.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        txt.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
```

Answer (score 7):

What I did was to create an extension to UITextField and added a Designer editable property. Setting this property to any color would change the border (bottom) to that color (setting other borders to none).

Since this also requires to change the place holder text color, I also added that to the extension.

```
    extension UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.placeHolderColor
        }
        set {
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: newValue!])
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable var bottomBorderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.bottomBorderColor
        }
        set {
            self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            let border = CALayer()
            let width = CGFloat(0.5)
            border.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width,   width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

            border.borderWidth = width
            self.layer.addSublayer(border)
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in Swift 4.0 you need to change the "set" to "didSet" but otherwise it works, thank you

Answer (score 6):

On Swift 3. You can create an extension and add after your view class.

```
extension UITextField
{
    func setBottomBorder(borderColor: UIColor)
    {

        self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let width = 1.0

        let borderLine = UIView()
        borderLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: Double(self.frame.height) - width, width: Double(self.frame.width), height: width)

        borderLine.backgroundColor = borderColor
        self.addSubview(borderLine)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only worked for me if you call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and not viewDidLoad(). Was that the intention here?

Answer (score 4):

Here is swift3 code with @IBInspectable

create a new file Cocoa Touch Class Swift File

```
import UIKit


extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
    }
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var leftBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return 0.0   // Just to satisfy property
    }
    set {
        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: newValue, height: bounds.height))
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
       line.tag = 110
        self.addSubview(line)

        let views = ["line": line]
        let metrics = ["lineWidth": newValue]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[line(==lineWidth)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[line]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
}

@IBInspectable var topBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return 0.0   // Just to satisfy property
    }
    set {
        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: bounds.width, height: newValue))
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = borderColor
       line.tag = 110
        self.addSubview(line)

        let views = ["line": line]
        let metrics = ["lineWidth": newValue]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[line]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[line(==lineWidth)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }
}

@IBInspectable var rightBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return 0.0   // Just to satisfy property
    }
    set {
        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: bounds.width, y: 0.0, width: newValue, height: bounds.height))
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = borderColor
       line.tag = 110
        self.addSubview(line)

        let views = ["line": line]
        let metrics = ["lineWidth": newValue]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "[line(==lineWidth)]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[line]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
}
@IBInspectable var bottomBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return 0.0   // Just to satisfy property
    }
    set {
        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: newValue))
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = borderColor
      line.tag = 110
        self.addSubview(line)

        let views = ["line": line]
        let metrics = ["lineWidth": newValue]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[line]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[line(==lineWidth)]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }
}
 func removeborder() {
      for view in self.subviews {
           if view.tag == 110  {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
           }

      }
 }
```

}

and replace the file with the below code and you will get the option in storyboard attribute inspector like this

[image]

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

** Here myTF is outlet for MT TEXT FIELD **

```
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.myTF.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.myTF.frame.size.width, height: self.myTF.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = width
        self.myTF.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.myTF.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

## SwiftUI

in SwiftUI, there is a `View` called `Divider` that is perfectly matched for this. You can add it below any view by embedding them into a simple `VStack`:

```
VStack {
    Text("This could be any View")
    Divider()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create one image for bottom border and set it to the background of your UITextField :

```
 yourTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBorderedImageName"]];
```

or set borderStyle to none and put image of line exactly equal length to textfield!

Comment: i ll have a look at this one saurabh.But it ll be great of we can make it by code?Do u have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Code:**

**Swift 5.0**

```
extension UITextField {
  func addUnderline() { 
   let layer = CALayer()
   layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
   layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1.0)
   self.clipsToBounds = true
   self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
   self.setNeedsDisplay()} }
```

Now call this func in **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    textField.addUnderline()
}
```

**NOTE:** This method will only work in **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at each of these solutions that also seem to work with one issue. Dark Mode and the background setting

The Background setting of the `UITextField` must match the background of the parent view or no line appears

So this will work on light mode
To get to work in dark mode change the background color to black and it works
Exclude back color and the line does not appear

```
let field = UITextField() 
field.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
field.bottomBorderColor = UIColor.red
```

This ended up being the best solution for me

```
extension UITextField {
      
    func addPadding() {
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 10, height: self.frame.height))
        self.leftView = paddingView
        self.leftViewMode = .always
      }
      
      @IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
          get {
              return self.placeHolderColor
          }
          set {
            self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: newValue!])
          }
      }
    
      @IBInspectable var bottomBorderColor: UIColor? {
          get {
              return self.bottomBorderColor
          }
          set {
            self.borderStyle = .none
            self.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let border = CALayer()
     let lineWidth = CGFloat(0.3)
     border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
     border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: emailTextField.frame.size.height - lineWidth, width:  emailTextField.frame.size.width, height: emailTextField.frame.size.height)
     border.borderWidth = lineWidth
     emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(border)
     emailTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[Tutorial](http://ios-tutorial.com/add-underline-uitextfield-swift/)

Comment: Work for me in swift 4.2

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, The simplest implementation would be,

```
struct MyTextField: View {
  var myPlaceHolder: String
  @Binding var text: String

  var underColor: Color
  var height: CGFloat

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField(self.myPlaceHolder, text: $text)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        .font(.title)

        Rectangle().frame(height: self.height)
            .padding(.horizontal, 24).foregroundColor(self.underColor)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyTextField(myPlaceHolder: "PlaceHolder", text: self.$text, underColor: .red, height: 3)
```

[image: Example Implementation]

Answer (score -1):

You can use this **ORGANIZED** and can also **CUSTOMIZE** this extension further:

> "**One Line Implementation**" in **viewDidAppear**(so that frame size will be correct):

```
// Add layer in your textfield    
yourTextField.addLayer(.bottom).addPadding(.left)


// Extension
    extension UITextField {

    enum Position {
        case up, bottom, right, left
    }

    //  MARK: - Add Single Line Layer
    func addLayer(_ position: Position) -> UITextField {

        // bottom layer
        let bottomLayer = CALayer()
        // set width
        let height = CGFloat(1.0)
        bottomLayer.borderWidth = height
        // set color
        bottomLayer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        // set frame
        // y position changes according to the position
        let yOrigin = position == .up ? 0.0 : frame.size.height - height
        bottomLayer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: yOrigin, width: frame.size.width, height: height)
        layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        return self
    }

    // Add right/left padding view in textfield
    func addPadding(_ position: Position, withImage image: UIImage? = nil) {
        let paddingHeight = frame.size.height
        let paddingViewFrame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: paddingHeight * 0.6, height: paddingHeight)
        let paddingImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: paddingViewFrame)
        paddingImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        if let paddingImage = image {
            paddingImageView.image = paddingImage
        }

        // Add Left/Right view mode
        switch position {
        case .left:
            leftView        = paddingImageView
            leftViewMode    = .always
        case .right:
            rightView       = paddingImageView
            rightViewMode    = .always
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIkit 

extension UITextField

{

func underlinedLogin()

{

    let border = CALayer()

    let width = CGFloat(1.0)

    border.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

}

call method on viewdidload

`mobileNumberTextField.underlinedLogin()`

`passwordTextField.underlinedLogin()`

//select like text field on mainstoryboard

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**For View : (Most Recommended)**

It works for all type of `UIView` subclass (view, textfiled, label, etc...) using `UIView extension`

It is more simple and convenient. But the only condition is the `view` must contain an auto layout.

```
extension UIView {
    enum Line_Position {
        case top
        case bottom
    }

    func addLine(position : Line_Position, color: UIColor, height: Double) {
        let lineView = UIView()
        lineView.backgroundColor = color
        lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This is important!
        self.addSubview(lineView)

        let metrics = ["width" : NSNumber(value: height)]
        let views = ["lineView" : lineView]
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[lineView]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))

        switch position {
        case .top:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[lineView(width)]", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        case .bottom:
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[lineView(width)]|", options:NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics:metrics, views:views))
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use?**

```
// UILabel
self.lblDescription.addLine(position: .bottom, color: UIColor.blue, height: 1.0)
```

[image]

and

```
// UITextField
self.txtArea.addLine(position: .bottom, color: UIColor.red, height: 1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove this line after setting it?
For example, I want to have it while my textField is active else I'd revert it to the default style.

Comment: yeah, simply hold object any remove or hide/show when you need it. :)