# UITextField having bottom border only in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am creating `UITextField` programatically and i am trying to create a `textField` that has only bottom border as given in the figure. Please help this problem in objective-c programatically ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField border for bottom side only in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800963/uitextfield-border-for-bottom-side-only-in-swift)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***First:***

Add and import `QuartzCore` framework.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

***Second:***

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
border.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
[textField.layer addSublayer:border];
textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

***EDIT:***

If you have more TextFields, make one common method which takes `UITextField` and applies border to it like below:

```
-(void)SetTextFieldBorder :(UITextField *)textField{

    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

Pass your TextField as follows to set Bottom Border:

```
[self SetTextFieldBorder:YourTextField];
```

Comment: If i have 10 ten textfields then what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add a thin line subview to the textfield that will mimic the border:

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] init];
lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[textField addSubview:lineView];

[lineView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1];
[lineView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:textField.leftAnchor constant:5.0];
[lineView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:textField.rightAnchor constant:-5.0];
[lineView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:textField.bottomAnchor constant:0.0];
```

Swift version:

```
let lineView = UIView()
lineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
textField.addSubview(lineView)

lineView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(1)
lineView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textField.leftAnchor)
lineView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textField.rightAnchor)
lineView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(textField.bottomAnchor)
```