# How to set only border bottom for textfield in IOS Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to IOS Xcode. I am building a login page in that I want the textField should show only the border-bottom and the storyboard should have a custom gradient background color. I referred many websites but I am not getting proper results. How to get it, please Help!

Comment: We don't know how your app is set up etc. It's only possible to give general answers that might be totally not applicable in your case. So please add some code and read the [Asking a question help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edit: Maybe [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800963/uitextfield-border-for-bottom-side-only-in-swift) might help you anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/26800963/5567142

Comment: Please follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800963/uitextfield-border-for-bottom-side-only-in-swift

Comment: hi Akaino, I am a javascript developer and I am not familiar with IOS. In my application, I have created a sample login page with username and password in Xcode. I am done with designing part but I don't have any idea about the coding part. Please let me know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the Answer , you can add the layer into your textField.
Just use the below code.**

> in below code , ***txtField*** means ***your textField in which you want to add
>   the border***.

```
let borderLayer = CALayer()
borderLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

// origin y should be height - 1
borderLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (txtField.frame.size.height - 1), size: CGSize(width: txtField.frame.size.width, height: 1.0))

txtField.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put a view under the textfeild with height of 1 and leading,trailingand bottom hooked to the textfeild