# Border width and placeholder in custom UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to make this TextField

[image]

So I write this class

```
class UnderLineTextField:UITextField{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkgray().cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - width, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

        textColor = UIColor.gold()
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        border.borderWidth = width
        layer.addSublayer(border)
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "",
                                                  attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkgray()])}
}
```

But there are two problems

1. The underline is not equal to TextField, if I add more width `width: frame.size.width + 500`, the problem can be fixed, but why? what is the correct value I should pass to `width:`?
2. `attributedPlaceholder` will replace the placeholder I set in xib, how can I change placeholder without adding empty string?

[image]

[image]

Comment: use ibinspectable for placeholder  ref :https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-3-702d7dd00ca

Comment: **Try this One** https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291113/10150796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The underline is not equal to TextField, if I add more width width: frame.size.width + 500, the problem can be fixed, but why? what is the correct value I should pass to width:?

You should put your draw underline code to `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` instead of `init`. Because of you using `autolayout`, so the width, that you got in `init` is difference with the `width` that you can see when run app.

> 2. attributedPlaceholder will replace the placeholder I set in xib, how can I change placeholder without adding empty string?

You can redraw the attributedPlaceholder base on your placeholder in `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`, too

```
attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
    string: self.placeholder,
    attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkgray()]
)
```

Comment: `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` is work, but placeholder is not, I tried to put `attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder!,
                                                   attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkgray()])` to `init` and `draw`, both of `self.placeholder!` are null

Comment: sorry, my mistake, now is ok, I put in to init, this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code is ok.

use below code for setting placeholder:

```
class UnderLineTextField:UITextField{

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor

        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var placeHolderText: String = "default place holder" {
        didSet {
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderText,
                                                       attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray])}

        }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.size.height - width, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

        textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        border.borderWidth = width
        layer.addSublayer(border)
        layer.masksToBounds = true

        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderText,
                                                   attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray])}
}
```

and set your placeholder in storyboard:
[image]

The result will look like below:

[image]

Comment: I think this is also good answer, but I still like the simplest one

Answer (score 0):

For `UITextField` underline use this one...

```
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(1.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = width
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey already lot of answers :), let's see if this detailed answer can help you achieve more:
I prefer using extensions over inheritance if possible.

```
extension UITextField {

func setTextColor(_ color: UIColor, font: UIFont) {

    self.textColor = color
    self.font = font
}

func setBottomBorder(with color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    self.borderStyle = .none
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor // bg color of your choice

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: width)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
}


func setPlaceHolderAttributes(placeHolderText : String, colour : UIColor , font : UIFont){

    self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeHolderText, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: colour , NSAttributedStringKey.font : font])
}
```

}

//MARK: To give text insets

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect.init(x:10, y:2, width:bounds.width-20, height:bounds.height - 4)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return textRect(forBounds: bounds)
}
```

}

And I prefer to configure UI from Code, it will fasten up your coding speed and achieve doing project wise change from one place, so you can do it from code like:

```
 let font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
    let placeHolderTextColor: UIColor = UIColor.brown
    let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkText

    nameTextField.setBottomBorder(with: UIColor.darkGray, width: 1.0)
    passwordTextField.setBottomBorder(with: UIColor.darkGray, width: 1.0)

    nameTextField.setPlaceHolderAttributes(placeHolderText: "Name", colour: placeHolderTextColor, font: font)
    nameTextField.setTextColor(textColor, font: font)

    passwordTextField.setPlaceHolderAttributes(placeHolderText: "Password", colour: placeHolderTextColor, font: font)
    passwordTextField.setTextColor(textColor, font: font)
```

[image]

Hope this helps :)